# How to align items in second (and further) column, so that the changing value (increasing characters) do not push

Tags: css, html, position, alignment, html-lists

I have a pretty specific question: I'm building something like a simple flat table (I don't use table itself because of rounded borders issue).

[image]

I'm using unordered list here and the problem is that I can't figure out how to align items in the second column, taking into account that the content should be dynamic (e.g. changing numbers).
Here's the markup for one row:

```
<section class="ktbl_head">
    <ul>
       <li>VALUE</li>
       <li>VALIDITY</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section class="ktbl_mid_wht">
    <ul>
       <li>500 units</li>
       <li>15 days</li>
       <button class="btn btn-sm getdramz pull-right">GET</button>
    </ul>
</section>
```

And CSS:

```
.ktbl_head {
padding: 15px 0 0 0;
height: 100%;
background-color: #ebe7e7;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.ktbl_head ul li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 135px;
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 300;
color: #888888;
}

.ktbl_mid_wht {
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 100%;
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.ktbl_mid_wht ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: left;
padding-right: 90px;
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
color: #888888;
}
```

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my implementation on aligning the table without the table tag:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="ktbl_head">
    <ul>
       <li>VALUE</li>
       <li>VALIDITY</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section class="ktbl_mid_wht">
    <ul>
       <li>500 units</li>
       <li>15 days</li>
       <button class="btn btn-sm getdramz pull-right">GET</button>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
    overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

section:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: #ebe7e7;
}

section ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 65px;
}

section ul li {
  width: 45%;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

section ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 35px;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Explanation**

You see, in the `HTML`, I added a new `div` as a container to create the curved corner with `border-radius` (the `overflow: hidden` needs to be used so that the content is encapsulated by the container).

For the `CSS`, `section` maintains general property such as `font-family`. Furthermore, `section:nth-child(2n+1)` is used to create `background-color` every other element starting with `1st,3rd,5th,...` element. The selectors `section ul`, `section ul li`, and `section ul li:first-child` are used to make the CSS selectors more semantic (it makes clean code and easy to maintain in the future). Please see the code below for the demo. Happy coding!

[PLAYGROUND](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/ApukF)

Answer (score 0):

Give all the li's a width in which all of the content-length will fit..